# firebase-functions: Unknown error status: TypeError: db.collectionGroup is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I added a collectionGroup query to my "firebase-functions" code. But now it gives me, this error: "Unknown error status: TypeError: db.collectionGroup is not a function". What did I wrong?

I updated my node.js, firebase and firebase-admin

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

let fetchQuery = db
      .collectionGroup("calendarIndex")
      .where("repeat", "==", false); 

fetchQuery
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => console.log(doc.data()));
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(err);
      });
```

Comment: What version of firebase-admin do you actually have installed?

Comment: I'm currently running firebase-admin version ~7.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your firebase-admin.  The latest at the time of this answer is 7.4.0.

```
npm install firebase-admin@latest
```

Collection group queries were introduced very recently, and your firebase-admin isn't recent enough to pick up the update to @google-cloud/firestore that added collection group queries in its [1.3 update on May 7](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes).